# Android Navigation library crash after sending data back

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

I use Android Navigation library for fragment navigation and try pass data back from second fragment to first. Do it with the next code:

```
findNavController().setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph, bundle)
findNavController().popBackStack()
```

It works fine, but when I try to open the same screen after it, the next error occurred:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination com.leshchenko.test:id/openPurchaseDetailsAction is unknown to this NavController
```

Thanks.

UPDATE: 
My nav_graph.xml

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/purchasesListFragment">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/purchasesListFragment"
    android:name="com.leshchenko.finance.presentation.purchases.PurchasesListFragment"
    android:label="fragment_purchases_list"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_purchases_list">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/openPurchaseDetailsAction"
        app:destination="@+id/purchaseDetailsFragment">
        <argument
            android:name="purchaseId"
            android:defaultValue="-1L"
            app:argType="long" />
    </action>
</fragment>
<fragment  
    android:id="@+id/purchaseDetailsFragment"
    android:name="com.leshchenko.finance.presentation.purchase_details.PurchaseDetailsFragment"
    android:label="fragment_purchase_details"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_purchase_details">
    <argument
        android:name="purchaseId"
        android:defaultValue="-1L"
        app:argType="long" />
</fragment>
```

Details opens via:

```
findNavController().navigate(PurchasesListFragmentDirections.openPurchaseDetailsAction())
```

Comment: post your `nav_graph.xml` and your fragment code.

Comment: @JohnJoe updated info

Comment: from `purchasesListFragment` to `purchaseDetailsFragment` , it works fine. Then you back from `purchaseDetailsFragment` to `purchasesListFragment`, it works fine too. But again from `purchasesListFragment` to `purchaseDetailsFragment`, it crashed?

Comment: @JohnJoe Yes, it is because `findNavController().setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph, bundle)`

Comment: maybe you can use `startActivityForResult`?

Comment: this helped https://medium.com/@Alex.v/android-navigation-architecture-component-25b5a7aab8aa

Answer (score 1):

use **findNavController().navigateUp()** instead of **findNavController().popBackStack()**

Comment: That's much safer than PopBackStack(). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just pass your data through viewModel and for fragment finish 
just use :

```
findNavController().popBackStack()
```

eg:

```
 view.setOnClickListener {
                // pass Data through ViewModel
                // viewModel.sendData(data)
                 Navigation.findNavController(it).popBackStack()
            }
```

Comment: It's not an option for me as fragments have different view models.